# error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I was trying to build a react app using Dotnet. I have installed dotnet but still getting this error. I have installed dotnet 5 and dotnet core 3.5. I have given the necessary images regarding the error.

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heutD.png)

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru8bZ.png)

[D:\dotnet project\Try\Try.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions (>= 5.0.9)' for 'net5.0'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m2CY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the version 5.0.1, [Link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0). I faced the same issue a while back and it was fixed by installing a lower version. If it doesn't work, then try installing version 4.8

Answer (score 12):

Oddly for my project, the user's computer couldn't find restorable packages because it didn't have a mapping for (the real) nuget.  We had to add (or run from powershell):

```
dotnet nuget add source --name nuget.org https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Then nuget restore worked and the error went away.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was doing my head in! I had no sources at all, why on earth the add package command doesn't tell you have no sources I have no idea! ‍♂️

Comment: This needs to be marked the answer -- very weird there was no sources, and it was also doing my head in when you can see the `lib/xxx/...` dirs being populated.

Answer (score 0):

Between older version of .NET 5.0 there has been an rename of the targetFramework.
[.net 5.0 vs netcoreapp5.0 Github](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/13295)

If your nuget package version doesn't contain your target framework,
please update or align the targetframework in your csproj file
with the contents of the nuget package or choose a more recent package.

Now it should be net5.0